# Java w/ LWJGL: Pixel Format Not Accelerated

Tags: java, windows, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to make a Game Engine. But have came over a problem in Java with its LWJGL and cant even run a window! Here's my code:

```
package Main;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main display = new Main();
        display.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            Window();
            InitGL();
            Run();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    DisplayMode displayMode;
    private void Window() throws Exception{
        Display.setFullscreen(false);
        DisplayMode d[] = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();
        for(int i =0; i < d.length; i++) {
            if(d[i].getWidth() == 640 && d[i].getHeight() == 480
                    && d[i].getBitsPerPixel() == 32) {
                displayMode = d[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        Display.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
        Display.setTitle("Game Engine");
        Display.create();
    }

    private void InitGL() {
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
        GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glClearDepth(1.0);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU.gluPerspective( // GLU cannot be resolved!  (Error)
                45.0f,
                (float)displayMode.getWidth()/(float)displayMode.getHeight(),
                0.1f, 100.0f);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
    }

    private void Run() {
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            try {
                Render();
                Display.update();
                Display.sync(30);
            }catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
        Display.destroy();
    }

    private void Render() {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    }
}
```

There is an error that i can't resolve on my own that is pointed out by quotations!

I an running this on a windows 10 system, running a laptop with an Intel Pentium Processor with integrated graphics. However this shouldn't make a difference, should just run slower.

I'd love anyone to help, sorry if this has already been answered, but I'm finding it hard to find the answer that fixes my problem.

I'm relatively new in Java but experienced in some other languages. Please don't ask why I want to do this, it's just something to keep me going.

Comment: You may be out of luck: http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5542.0

Comment: ok thanks, do u know how i would fix it? plus im using 2.9.3 i think? do i need to use slick-util? coz thats a package i have?

Comment: I'm no expert, I just came across this question while doing triage for StackOverflow. I would check around that forum and the project's github issues to see if anybody has a fix.